# Error : Erroneous command line argument 4 (bootstrap1)

Tags: tezos-client, address, bootstrapping

What are the possible reasons for getting this error? And why I am getting the error

```
Error:
  Erroneous command line argument 4 (bootstrap1).
  no public key hash alias named bootstrap1
  cannot read file (Unix.Unix_error(Unix.ENOENT, "open", "bootstrap1"))
  Failed to read a b58check_encoding data (Signature.Public_key_hash): "bootstrap1"
```

Comment: It would be extremely helpful to show us what command you executed to get this error.

Comment: Please offer additional context @cryptoscroller